# access - reset all comboboxes to itemdata(1) in form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, combobox

I have about 8 combo-boxes on a form. When a user clicks the button "reset"  I would like all the combo boxes to display the first itemdata in the combo box. The code below returns null and doesn't work:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
     Me.Combo1.ItemData (1)
     Me.Combo2.ItemData (1)
     Me.Combo3.ItemData (1)
     Me.Combo4.ItemData (1)
     Me.Combo5.ItemData (1)
     Me.Combo6.ItemData (1)
     Me.Combo7.ItemData (1)
     Me.Combo8.ItemData (1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's MS Access your working with, you'll need to do something like this:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
     Me.Combo1.Value = Nothing
     Me.Combo2.Value = Nothing
     Me.Combo3.Value = Nothing
     Me.Combo4.Value = Nothing
     Me.Combo5.Value = Nothing
     Me.Combo6.Value = Nothing
     Me.Combo7.Value = Nothing
     Me.Combo8.Value = Nothing
End Sub
```

Assuming you want to set all the ComboBoxes back to a blank value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
     Me.Combo1.SelectedIndex = 0
     Me.Combo2.SelectedIndex = 0
     Me.Combo3.SelectedIndex = 0
     Me.Combo4.SelectedIndex = 0
     Me.Combo5.SelectedIndex = 0
     Me.Combo6.SelectedIndex = 0
     Me.Combo7.SelectedIndex = 0
     Me.Combo8.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: SelectedIndex doesnt seem to exist as an option via intellisense.

Comment: Then use `Me.Combo1.Value = Nothing` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `Me.Combo1.SelectedIndex = 0`

Usually...